# Spree installation -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm getting troubles to install spree. After installing all necessary gems, I launched the following commands :

```
rails _4.2.2_ new my_store
spree install my_store
```

I didn't get any error message but when I launch "rails s", I get the spree homepage with nothing else but "No products found" message.

Any clue about what could be wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will need to install the spree gem in your environment if you haven't installed yet

```
gem install spree_cmd
```

Then you need to create a rails project

```
rails new my_store
```

After created your rails project run this command, this must be run outside of your project folder

```
spree install my_store
```

Finally it will prompt some questions in the terminal (if you want to run seed, which have the default data), you must answer that with a yes (y) or not (n) depending on what do you want to install (i'd recommend you to say yes to all)

And now you will have your Spree project running with all the default configuration and data.

Answer (score 2):

simple spree installation does not give sample data or product , you have to install it via command `bundle exec rake spree_sample:load`

Comment: I got the following message :

Comment: MYPROMPT $ bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
[WARNING] You are not setting Devise.secret_key within your application!
You must set this in config/initializers/devise.rb. Here's an example:
 
Devise.secret_key = "d3c918a9611ca9038eef526b1985ae0c8c4d07aab714ce7173f48329a60169dbe75d491bad95a4ae488660ebba3161eda1b8"
Loaded Payment Methods samples
Loaded Shipping Categories samples
Couldn't find 'North America' zone. Did you run `rake db:seed` first?
That task will set up the countries, states and zones required for Spree.

Comment: your database is not installed with proper data check it again

Comment: if you can delete all the data which is currently have in application then run this command one by one `bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rake spree_sample:load`

Comment: bundle exec rake db:seed
[WARNING] You are not setting Devise.secret_key within your application!
You must set this in config/initializers/devise.rb. Here's an example:
 
Devise.secret_key = "1f7525518a31ae388545481dfad9122f664bcf94cf1d49b994ea5693e4dfdea6c6aa5d63a3e30ad7632c85107e5bc3232859"
loading ruby /Users/karimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.4/db/default/spree/countries.rb
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error:   INSERT INTO spree_countr.....

Comment: Hey don't use sqlite use pgsql or mysql

Comment: @skessmousse I was the guy who did the spree_countries SQL import. I think you'll find 2 previous comments by me on this thread. Let me see if I can get the SQLite issue fixed/recreated. Do you know what version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

For sure something wrong with sqlite database but still don't know what ...
I just created a new rails projects using mysql database :

```
rails new myproject -d mysql
```

Then :

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Finally :

```
spree install myproject
```

Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Spree supports MySQL and SQLite, but there's even more fine-grained support for PostgreSQL. Also, when Rails launches a new DB feature, its usually PG that gets it first. If you figure out what the issue was, can you open an issue on Spree please?

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because rake is aborted and states and cities are not completely loaded.

There is a simple temporary solution to finish the rake and load all the sample data.

```
bundle exec rake db:drop
```

Then open the spree_core gem using

```
bundle open spree_core
```

Make the tweaks according to

```
spree_core/db/default/spree/countries.rb

require 'carmen'

Carmen::Country.all.map do |country|
  name = country.name
  iso3 = country.alpha_3_code
  iso = country.alpha_2_code
  iso_name = country.name.upcase
  numcode = country.numeric_code
  states_required = country.subregions?

  # country_inserts << [name, iso3, iso, iso_name, numcode, states_required].join(", ")
  Spree::Country.new(      :name => name,
      :iso3 => iso3,
      :iso => iso,
      :iso_name => iso_name,
      :numcode => numcode,
      :states_required => states_required
  ).save!
end

canada = Spree::Country.find_by(iso: "CA")
Spree::Config[:default_country_id] = canada.id
```

and

```
spree_core/db/default/spree/states.rb

connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
state_inserts = []

Spree::Country.where(states_required: true).each do |country|
  carmen_country = Carmen::Country.named(country.name)
  carmen_country.subregions.each do |subregion|
    name = connection.quote subregion.name
    abbr = connection.quote subregion.code
    country_id = connection.quote country.id

    state_inserts << [name, abbr, country_id].join(", ")
    Spree::State.new(:name => name, :abbr => abbr, :country_id => country_id).save!
  end
end
```

Then do

```
bundle exec rake db: create
bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
```

Hope this solves you issue

Thank you

Reference:- https://askubuntu.com/questions/658049/spree-sample-data-fetch-giving-error-on-bundle-exec-rake-dbseed

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing the local spree file. The country and state data also probably shouldn't be edited, mainly because if a bug occurs and its fixed in master, then @skess isn't going to get it. Not to mention you can't deploy with this. Running `rake db:seed` is kinda nice when setting up production. Also, I updated Spree to use SQL instead so that loading up a sandbox doesn't take 10 seconds. The ~3000 states are now lighting fast.

Comment: I just had a tweak @BenMorganIO . This tweak was for setting up in local. Sorry If I went on wrong suggestions.

Comment: It looks like this is the best solution if you're pre-3.7.11. Back when multiple inserts had to be done over `UNION`s...

Comment: I am using sqlite3 version 3.8.7.3 and I got this error too. @BenMorganIO

Comment: @newguy that's not good. Since your comment was 2 days ago, there's a new project called Solidus that I believe has fixed 90% of the Spree issues. Was the issue with the EOL Spree project or with the Solidus project?

Comment: @BenMorganIO I was deploying it on my Mac Yosemite though. On Linode CentOS I don't have this problem. I have tried Solidus but unfortunately there are also limited resources for this project. I can't even make Spree_bootstrap_frontend work on Solidus. To rewrite the whole frontend is not an option for me at the moment unless I can find a good theme that works on Solidus.

Comment: I would just copy and paste the frontend in TBH. Solidus actually wants to deprecate the frontend and for good reason too.

Comment: @BenMorganIO what does TBH mean? I know there is a good reason to untie the frontend from the backend but from an end user's perspective it requires quite a learning curve to make the site look like a modern ecommerce website if there is no free theme or extension to start with.

Comment: TBH = To Be Honest. I think it being pulled out is a good idea. If people want different themes, they could make their own `solidus_frontend` gems.

Comment: And I'm sure Solidus would put their frontend in its own gem as well. That way there's an easier upgrade path. Spree is notoriously bad at providing an upgrade path. Solidus will most likely do it the right way.